# elasticsearch - group and filter result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of DocumentVersions - different versions of a document.

```
{versionId: 1, documentId:1, ...},
{versionId: 2, documentId:1, ...},
{versionId: 3, documentId:2, ...},
{versionId: 4, documentId:2, ...},
...
```

By default users should only receive the **most recent version of a document**.

In **Solr** i used **ResultGrouping** - `group.field=documentId, group.limit=1, group.sort=versionId desc`.

How can i achieve something similar with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a terms aggregation on `documentId` and a `top_hits` sub-aggregation

```
POST /index/_search
{  
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "docs": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "documentId",
            "size": 1000
         },
         "aggs": {
            "latest": {
               "top_hits": {
                  "size": 1,
                  "sort": {"versionId": "desc"}
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I already thought about aggregations, but my problem is that the result looks completely different (i am working an a very generic search implementation). Is there a way to "repack" or "flatten" the response - solr has `group.format` and `group.main` for that.

Comment: Do you really need the older versions?

Comment: Yes, i need the older versions as well.

Comment: How should i implement paging if  i go with terms- and tophits-aggregation? If i set `size` for the terms aggregation i loose the number of totalHits.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [Field Collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html) - which actually is based on aggregations :-/

Wish there was a more convenient way.